# SQL On Delete Trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, database-trigger

I am trying to create a trigger that when a row is deleted from a table it gets inserted in another table:

```
  1 Create Or Replace Trigger cancel
  2 After Delete
  3         On OrderTable
  4         For EACH ROW
  5 Begin
  6         Insert Into CancelledOrders Values (:old.acctNum, age, phone)
  7         From OrderTable Natural Join Customer
  8         Where acctid = :old.acctNum AND menuid = :old.menuNum;
  9 End;
 10 /
 11 Show Errors;
```

I want to grab the `acctNum`, `age`, and `phone`. The `acctNum` is from the Order table but the `age` and `phone` is from the Customer table. Therefore I join the two tables (on the `acctid` key). So the joined result will look like this:

`acctNum Age Phone`

I get this error when I try to compile the Trigger:

```
2/2  PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
3/2  PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Does anyone know the problem?

**EDIT:**
Table Structure:

OrderTable: `AcctNum MenuNum startOrder endOrder`
Customer Table: `AcctNum age phone`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing the [`values` and `select` (subquery) syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9014.htm#i2121671), which are for different things. You can insert from a query that uses a value from the `:old` pseudorecord and values from the customer table:

```
    Insert Into CancelledOrders -- (acctNum, age, phone)
    Select :old.acctNum, age, phone
    From Customer
    Where acctNum = :old.acctNum;
```

It's better to specify the columns in the target table as part of the insert clause (I've left that commented out in case the names are different). You also don't want (or need) to requery the table the trigger is against; you already have the data you need, and it will get a mutating-table error in some circumstances. So no join is needed.

Comment: In the `where` clause where you do `:old.acctNum` refers only to the table where the rows were deleted correct? It knows the table where the rows were deleted from?

Comment: @1290 - the `:old` refers to the pseudorecord, since this is a `for each row` trigger. So it will use the value form the row that is being deleted, yes. It isn't querying that table directly. Oh wait, yes it is, but it shouldn't be, I'll need to fix that - can you add the table structures to the question so I can see what is coming from each?

Comment: Ohh I see now. But since I joined the tables the deleted row (from OrderTable) will be joined from another row in the Customer Table. So basically old will refer to that combined row with the deleted values from the Order Table.

Comment: Oh so I don't need to `Natural Join` since I already specified the table the row is being deleted from after the `After Delete` line?

Comment: So the natural join was on `acctNum`? I've updated to take that join out since you don't need to look at `orderTable` again. I don't know where `menuNum` sits though, that isn't in your edit. If it's in `orderTable` you don't need it either.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just added menuNum which sits in the OrderTable.

Comment: OK, great, I've taken that reference out now too. So it's a pretty simple statement in the end *8-)

Answer (score 0):

Your insert statement is incorrect. You need to specify the columns you want to select in the tables.

Add the `select` clause to your insert statement. Also, removed the `values` keyword and specify column names:

```
  Insert Into CancelledOrders (acctNum, age, phone)
  Select :old.acctNum, age, phone
  From OrderTable Natural Join Customer
  Where acctid = :old.acctNum AND menuid = :old.menuNum;
```